# AngularJS - one of my directives don't work, the others do?

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, html

I've recently been getting into looking for a job and decided to build a website as kind of a resume and while doing this learning AngularJS at the same time. I took CodeSchools Angular course and slowly building this website like I want it. (Please don't judge it based on how it looks right now, but ideas are apprechiated)

Now to the code problem!

Website:
http://danieboy.github.io/

Index.html (start, resume, reviews and contact working - **myprojects don't**)

```
<div class="content-wrap">
          <section id="section-shape-1">
            <start></start>
          </section>

          <section id="section-shape-2">
            <resume></resume>
          </section>

          <section id="section-shape-3">
            <myprojects></myprojects>
          </section>

          <section id="section-shape-4">
            <reviews></reviews>
          </section>

          <section id="section-shape-5">
            <contact></contact>
          </section>
        </div>
```

myDirectives.js

```
    var app = angular.module('blog-directives', []);

app.directive("start", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "start.html"
    }
});

app.directive("resume", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "resume.html"
    }
});

app.directive("myprojects", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "myprojects.html"
    }
});

app.directive("reviews", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "reviews.html"
    }
});

app.directive("contact", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "contact.html"
    }
});
```

start.html **(working)**

```
    <h1>
    <a id="welcome-to-my-developer-blog" class="anchor" href="#welcome-to-my-developer-blog" aria-hidden="true"><span class="octicon octicon-link"></span></a>Welcome to my developer blog!</h1>
*Text...*
<img src="images/Web-under-construction.jpeg" alt="Under Construction"></br>
```

myprojects.html **(not working)**

```
<h3><a href="http://danieboy.github.io/hotorcold"> Hot or Cold</a></h3>
<h3><a href="http://danieboy.github.io/flatlander-store/index.html"> Flatlander Store Project</a></h3>
<h3><a href="http://danieboy.github.io/bmi-calculator/index.html"> Android Application: BMI-counter</a></h3>
<h3><a href="http://www.markettime.se/"> Markettime through Diflex AB (Swedish)</a></h3>
<h3><a href="http://test2.markettools.se"> Markettools through Diflex AB (Swedish)</a></h3>
```

I really have no idea why four of them would work but not the 5th.

I accidentally created the file at first with the name MyProjects instead of myprojects and deleted it, but I may have mistakenly not have crossed safe delete because I was thinking that it wouldn't matter since I'm creating the same file again. Could that be a problem? In the .idea/workspace.xml file which auto updates (I use WebStorm 10.1)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks nice though, I'm sure you'll find a job in no time ;)

Comment: change myprojects.html to myProjects.html xD

Comment: This was infact a working solution...I don't really understand why tho. Nowhere in the code was it written as myProjects. It was written myprojects everywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows the following stacktrace in the Chrome console:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: myprojects.html
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$compile/tpload?p0=myprojects.html
    at angular.js:78
    at angular.js:6576
    at angular.js:7740
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedErrback (angular.js:11109)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedErrback (angular.js:11109)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedErrback (angular.js:11109)
    at angular.js:11242
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12175)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12004)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12279)
```

So you probably just misplaced your myprojects.html.

When I navigate to http://danieboy.github.io/myprojects.html it says 404, so this confirms that this is the problem.

Comment: as YOU said in the comment...changing the name to myProjects worked. And I have no idea why since it was written as myproject EVERYWHERE in the code. Nevertheless thank you :)

Comment: O YOU... I was thinking, hey I didn't say that!

Comment: Haha indeed a very confusing name!